# pandas rolling with multiple values per time step

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time, rolling-computation

I'm trying to do an anomaly detection using python, with a rolling window of 8 days value to calculate the interquartile range for the two metrics (err_precent, and fail precent). The [examples provided](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.window.Rolling.quantile.html) seems only have one value per timestamp/index, where in my case I have many.

My data looks like this:

```
        customerID   err_precent   fail_precent
end_date            
2019-05-02  29616   0.857143    1.000000
2019-05-02  277023  1.000000    1.000000
2019-05-02  150560  1.000000    1.000000
2019-05-02  88778   1.000000    1.000000
... ... ... ...
2019-06-10  67311   1.000000    1.000000
2019-06-10  128116  1.000000    1.000000
2019-06-10  264288  0.935484    1.000000
2019-06-10  199984  0.941176    1.000000
2019-06-10  444105  0.952381    0.857143
2019-06-10  388703  0.894737    0.947368
2019-06-10  138986  1.000000    1.00000
```

After doing the rolling on the data columns, I can see there are many values for each day. The question is: can I use all the values per 8 days to calculate a single quantile value instead of having quantiles for each customer, like following?

```
         err_precent    fail_precent
end_date        
2019-05-02  0.857143    1.000000
2019-05-03  0.900000    0.880000
2019-05-04  0.900000    0.880000
...
2019-06-10  0.857143    0.941176
```

```py
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.end_date, format='%m/%d/%Y')
df[dataColumn].rolling('8D', min_periods =1 ).quantile(.25, interpolation = 'lower')
```

The undesired result, as you can see there are many quantile values for each day is returned.

```
          err_precent   fail_precent
end_date        
2019-05-02  0.857143    1.000000
2019-05-02  0.857143    1.000000
2019-05-02  0.857143    1.000000
2019-05-02  0.857143    1.000000
2019-05-02  1.000000    1.000000
2019-05-02  0.941176    1.000000
2019-05-02  0.941176    1.000000
2019-05-02  0.857143    0.941176
2019-05-02  0.923077    1.000
... ... ...
2019-06-10  0.900000    0.880000
2019-06-10  0.900000    0.880000
2019-06-10  0.900000    0.880000
2019-06-10  0.900000    0.880000
2019-06-10  0.900000    0.880000
2019-06-10  0.900000    0.880000
2019-06-10  0.900000    0.880000
2019-06-10  0.900000    0.880000
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured a walkaround for this issue by using resample, first calculated the quantile per day through resample, then do a rolling average with the previous 8 days.

```
lb = df[dataColumn].resample("1d").quantile(.25).fillna(0).rolling(window=8).mean()
```